# What exactly is impacting the compute throughput of the SM units?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu

I have written a simple kernel function and I'm attempting to optimize it.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void addArray(float*array1,float *array2,float *resultArray,int arrayLen) {
    int range = arrayLen / (blockDim.x * gridDim.x) +1;
    int start = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)*range;
    int end = start + range;
    end = end <= arrayLen ? end : arrayLen;
    
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        resultArray[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
    }
}

void printErorr() {
    auto e = cudaGetLastError();
    if (e != cudaSuccess)
        std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(e) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int arrayLen = 1e8;
    const float a1 = 10, a2 = 3;
    float* array1 = new float[arrayLen];
    float* array2 = new float[arrayLen];
    float* resultArray = new float[arrayLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = a1;
        array2[i] = a2;
    }

    float* d_array1, *d_array2,*d_resultArray;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array1, sizeof(float) * arrayLen);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array2, sizeof(float) * arrayLen);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_resultArray, sizeof(float) * arrayLen);
    
    cudaMemcpy(d_array1, array1, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_array2, array2, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    addArray << <24, 64 >> > (d_array1, d_array2, d_resultArray, arrayLen);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printErorr();

    cudaMemcpy(array1, d_array1, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(array2, d_array2, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(resultArray, d_resultArray, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printErorr();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
    {
        if (abs(resultArray[i] -( a1 + a2)) < 1e-4)
            continue;
        std::cerr << "erorr index :" << i  << "  value: "<< resultArray[i] << std::endl;
    }


    cudaFree(d_array1);
    cudaFree(d_array2);
    cudaFree(d_resultArray);
    return 0;
}
```

For the invocation parameters `<<<24, 512>>>`, the execution time is 16ms, while for `<<<72, 512>>>`, it's 22ms.

Analyzing the invocation parameters `<<<24, 512>>>`, theoretically, these parameters aren't optimal because with 512 threads per block, which translates to 16 warps per block, to achieve 100% theoretical warp occupancy, three thread blocks are required to fully occupy an SM unit. Therefore, a grid size of 24 won't completely fill 24 SM units.

Upon testing, the actual occupancy with these parameters is indeed low, but surprisingly, the cache hit rate is high, possibly due to the simplicity of the calculations.

Updating the parameters to `<<<72, 512>>>`:
[image-20240314163537836 http://image.cppdebug.com/images/2024/03/15/image-202403141635378362b01859ff55a21bc.png](http://image.cppdebug.com/images/2024/03/15/image-202403141635378362b01859ff55a21bc.png)

The warp occupancy is maximized, but the cache hit rate has significantly decreased, leading to a decline in memory throughput, subsequently affecting the compute throughput of the SM units.

This seems to be a structural issue within the code. With this code structure, where multiple blocks are placed into the same SM unit and the threads in the SM unit are maximized, the data entering the L1 cache may not persist until the second loop iteration before being evicted to accommodate data access by other threads.

Based on these speculations, I have made modifications to the code.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void addArray(float* array1, float* array2, float* resultArray, int arrayLen) {
    int range = arrayLen / (blockDim.x * gridDim.x) + 1;
    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
    {
        index = start + i * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
        if (index >= arrayLen)
            break;
        resultArray[index] = array1[index] + array2[index];
    }
}

void printErorr() {
    auto e = cudaGetLastError();
    if (e != cudaSuccess)
        std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(e) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int arrayLen = 1e8;
    const float a1 = 10, a2 = 3;
    float* array1 = new float[arrayLen];
    float* array2 = new float[arrayLen];
    float* resultArray = new float[arrayLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = a1;
        array2[i] = a2;
    }

    float* d_array1, * d_array2, * d_resultArray;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array1, sizeof(float) * arrayLen);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_array2, sizeof(float) * arrayLen);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_resultArray, sizeof(float) * arrayLen);

    cudaMemcpy(d_array1, array1, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_array2, array2, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    addArray << <72, 512 >> > (d_array1, d_array2, d_resultArray, arrayLen);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printErorr();

    cudaMemcpy(array1, d_array1, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(array2, d_array2, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(resultArray, d_resultArray, sizeof(float) * arrayLen, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printErorr();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
    {
        if (abs(resultArray[i] - (a1 + a2)) < 1e-4)
            continue;
        std::cerr << "erorr index :" << i << "  value: " << resultArray[i] << std::endl;
    }


    cudaFree(d_array1);
    cudaFree(d_array2);
    cudaFree(d_resultArray);
    return 0;
}
```

`<<<72, 512>>>` Time Consumption: 5ms

Magical!
[image-20240315163356178 http://image.cppdebug.com/images/2024/03/15/image-20240315163356178c959143ddc6357f5.png](http://image.cppdebug.com/images/2024/03/15/image-20240315163356178c959143ddc6357f5.png)

From the analysis, it appears that while the cache hit rate has decreased significantly, the compute throughput of the SM units has increased. This leaves me puzzled as to what exactly affects the compute throughput of the SM units.

Comment: This kernel seems *memory-bound*, not compute-bound. The former seems to to strided accesses while the later do contiguous access. *Coalesced* memory accesses are critical for good performance of memory-bound kernels on GPUs (at least for the global memory). Other things does not matter much. You just need the number of thread to be a multiple of the size of a warp, at least few warp by block and enough block so to saturate all SM (AFAIK the GPU memory should be saturated even using only a part of all the SM).

Comment: If you just want to travel the array, then this is a complicated way of doing that IMHO. You can just do : `for(int i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x ; i<arrayLen ; i+=blockDim.x) { ... }`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You mean `i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x`.

Comment: This kind of loop is called a grid-stride loop and recommended in many CUDA tutorials due to its simplicity and the fact that this makes it very hard to completely screw up the launch parameters. A block-stride loop might be even better for performance due to locality, but it is easier to screw up when the work isn't divisible by the block size.

Comment: Please upload your images to Imgur or any other site that allows access through https, so your images can be properly embedded.

Comment: See [CUDA C++ Best Practices Guide: Coalesced Access to Global Memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) to get an understanding of coalescing and its performance implications.

Comment: @paleonix Ah right, thank you. I use do write block-stride loops more often so I missed the grid factor ;) .

Comment: Basically everything comes down to handling CUDA threads more like SIMD lanes than CPU threads in terms of memory access.